# I use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to rotation a label, why only text rotated？

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, uilabel

My code like that:

```
[label2 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
```

Before rotation like follow

[image]

After rotation like that

[image]

Anybody can tell me why, thank you?

Comment: How are you drawing the green rectangle? Is it just the background color of the text field? If so, then it's probably drawing correctly. Changing the transformation won't transform the bounding rectangle of the view inside it's container - only what's drawn inside the view. If you want to change the frame of the view, you need to do that manually.

Comment: @user1118321 first thank you. If so how can i rotation the label frame any angle?

Comment: @Dracuuula here angle in radians, just set proper value to makeRotation and if need you can perform transformation to label superview

Comment: Do you set frame property after applying the transformation?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
-(NSPoint)rotatePoint:(NSPoint)inPt
          aroundPoint:(NSPoint)center
            withAngle:(double)radians
{
    NSPoint temp = {inPt.x - center.x, inPt.y - center.y};
    double sinAngle = sin(radians);
    double cosAngle = cos(radians);
    NSPoint result;
    result.x = temp.x * cosAngle - temp.y * sinAngle;
    result.y = temp.x * sinAngle + temp.y * cosAngle;

    result.x += center.x;
    result.y += center.y;
}
```

Then call the above method for the 4 corners of the frame of the view you're rotating, and set the frame to the new values.

Comment: I understand what you said, but is there have a API set the frame with 4 corners' value?

Comment: I don't believe so. You can transform the 4 points, then take the min and max of the x and y coordinates, and use those to make the new rectangle.